# inline jquery thick box does not close with javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues with jquery inline thickbox in the classic asp app.
The code looks like this:

The properties of the hyperlink tags are as under:

```
<a>href="#TB_inline?height=295&width=604&inlineId=rev-modal" onclick="GetAuth()" id="btnAuthorize" class="thickbox">Authorize</a>
```

Now I have created a javascript that makes ajax call and based on the results it either shows error or moves ahead. Inside my javascript I show the error div and close the thick box. It was working fine with the ajax callback items/erros. But now I have added javascript validation to the page. Now my thickbox does not go away when if invalid input is found. I can see the error div and error from the javascript validation but its all inside the gray transparent thickbox thing which I dont want. When I click on the page the thickbox goes away.

My javascript is like this :

```
function GetAuth() {
    if (ValidInputs() == "" ) {

    }
    else {
        $("#errordiv").show();
        $("#errordetail").html(ValidInputs());
        self.parent.tb_remove();
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error.

    <a href="#TB_inline?height=295&width=604&inlineId=rev-modal" onclick="GetAuth()" id="btnAuthorize" class="thickbox">Authorize</a>

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your anchor.  Also, I would structure your code more like this.

Also, if you would make a jsfiddle for questions like this it'd be easier for the people answering to test: http://jsfiddle.net.

```
function GetAuth() {
    if (ValidInputs() != "" ) {
        $("#errordetail").html(ValidInputs());
        $("#errordiv").show();
        self.parent.tb_remove();
     }else
     {
          alert('Did you expect this to happen?');
     }
     return false;
}

<a href="#TB_inline?height=295&width=604&inlineId=rev-modal&modal=true" onclick="GetAuth()" id="btnAuthorize" class="thickbox">Authorize</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. I finally resolved it by moving all my validation into the call back page itself.